# Optuna pruned trial for random forest classifier

Tags: logistic-regression, random-forest, cart, hyperparameters, optuna

I am currently working on Optuna library and I have seen that there is a parameter which allows to prune unpromissing trials. It seems that this parameter can only be used with incremental learning method such as SGD classifier or with neural network.
Hence, I was wondering, is it possible to use prune trials when using a random forest, a decision dree CART or even a logistic regression ?

Thanks a lot ! :)

PS : I did not find any example on the internet which used random forest with pruned trials using optuna ...

Answer (score 0):

`SGDClassifier` with `loss='cross_entropy'` performs logistic regression, enabling you to use incremental learning for logistic regression.

As for random forests and decsion trees; they are batch learners, so trial pruning doesn't apply. However, you can wrap batch learners in a class (`PseudoIncrementalBatchLearner` below) that refits the learner on more and more data each time you call `partial_fit()`. This is similar to how a learning curve is generated, where the estimator is refitted on increasing portions of the dataset.

In general, as a learner is fit on larger portions of the data, its generalisation error will go down - the trend is somewhat predictable for an individual estimator. However, when *comparing* learners, you might like to prune ones that are relatively slow to improve, and which are too expensive to train on the entire dataset...this is where `PsueoIncrementalBatchLearner` below could be useful.

The data + example below shows how the blue random forest is slow to improve compared to the orange one, and therefore the blue one is a candidate for early pruning. This avoids you having to train the learner on the full dataset (although at the end they're comparable).

[image]

```py
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import base
import numpy as np

#
#Wraps a batch learner, training it on larger portions of the data
# each time partial_fit() is called
#
class PseudoIncrementalBatchLearner(
    base.BaseEstimator,
    base.MetaEstimatorMixin,
    base.ClassifierMixin,
    base.RegressorMixin
):
    def __init__(self, estimator, max_steps=20, random_state=None):
        self.estimator = estimator
        self.max_steps = max_steps
        self.random_state = random_state
    
    def partial_fit(self, X, y):
        X, y = base.check_X_y(X, y)
            
        if hasattr(X, 'columns'):
            self.feature_names_in_ = np.array(
                X.columns, dtype='object'
            )
        self.n_features_in_ = X.shape[1]
        
        if not hasattr(self, 'current_step_'):
            self.current_step_ = 0
        
        #Get ShuffleSplit/StratifiedShuffleSplit for regressor/classifier
        cv = getattr(
            model_selection,
            ('Stratified' if base.is_classifier(self.estimator) else '') + 'ShuffleSplit'
        )
        
        #Shuffle and split off the required size for this step
        if self.current_step_ + 1 < self.max_steps:
            train_ix, _ = next(cv(
                n_splits=1, train_size=(self.current_step_ + 1) / self.max_steps
            ).split(X, y))
        else:
            train_ix = np.arange(len(X))

        #Beyond max_steps, no more refitting, as already fit on all data.
        # Could optionally comment this part out.
        if self.current_step_ + 1 > self.max_steps:
            return self
        
        #Refit estimator on the current portion of the dataset
        self.estimator_ = base.clone(self.estimator).fit(X[train_ix], y[train_ix])
        self.current_step_ += 1
        return self
    
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.estimator_.predict(X)


#
#Make test dataset
#
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=500, noise=0.2, random_state=0)
X_val, y_val = make_moons(n_samples=200, noise=0.2, random_state=1)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap='coolwarm')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 3)
plt.show()

#Create two classifiers to see which learns in fewer steps.
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf0 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))
rf1 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=np.random.RandomState(1))

pi_rf0 = PseudoIncrementalBatchLearner(rf0, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))
pi_rf1 = PseudoIncrementalBatchLearner(rf1, random_state=np.random.RandomState(1))

#Run pseudo-incremental training (training on larger portions of same data, each step)
val_scores0, val_scores1 = [], []
for i in range(pi_rf0.max_steps):
    pi_rf0.partial_fit(X, y)
    pi_rf1.partial_fit(X, y)
    
    val_scores0.append(pi_rf0.score(X_val, y_val))
    val_scores1.append(pi_rf1.score(X_val, y_val))

#Plot results
plt.plot(val_scores0, lw=2, label='rf0 validation')
plt.plot(val_scores1, lw=2, label='rf1 validation')
plt.xlabel('training "step" (i.e. proportion of the training data)')
plt.gca().set_xticks(range(pi_rf0.max_steps))
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 2.5)
plt.gcf().legend()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is now clear that I can't use early pruning in optuna when dealing with random forest/decision trees. 

For the remark : " `SGDClassifier` with `loss='cross_entropy'` performs logistic regression, enabling you to use incremental learning for logistic regression. " I also want to thank you because I didn't know ! It will be quite useful.